# React Router imposes its own Navbar Styles. I can change the link styles but I am still left with borders and padding which I can't get rid of

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router

I am using React Router, which works well enough.  However, the NavBar which comes with the router has style elements that I ewant to override.   I can change the link font and colour but I can't get rid of the borders or the padding, which means my navbar is too wide and too tall.  If I look in chrome developer it seems there is a navbar style of "sc-hKgJUU caLaoV" which I cannot override.

This is what I see in Chrome developer tools

```
<ul class="sc-bdfBQB iGWAPe">
<a href="/"><li>Home</li></a>
<a href="/introduction">
<li>Introduction</li>
</a>
</ul>
```

How can I override this to reduce the padding etc ?

Comment: You use style sheets (css) to customise the look of the website.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  The Router Navbar code isn't accessible for the user to modify the elements as far as I can see.